# boost::spirit reusage of grammar objects

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Imagine there is a rule to parse some name:

```
m_sName = qi::lexeme[
    (ascii::alpha | qi::char_('_')) >> *(ascii::alnum | qi::char_('_'))
]
```

Could one use the same object for parsing two names in series or does one have to instantiate m_sName1 and m_sName2?

```
m_sName >> m_sName
```

Comment: What prompts this question? It seems to me that something else than `m_sName >> m_sName` makes no sense, and you would have your answer in 10s of trying. Well 30s on a slow compiler. Is there a context where this is not working the way you expected it to work?

Comment: @sehe
I had a grammar in which until now I had used multiple copies of the same grammar because I somehow had the (wrong?) notion that they must be separate.

Comment: You can see a parser epression as a declarative specification of a `parse()` function. All state goes in via arguments. (Of course your own grammars might add instance state if you want, but then it becomes harder to reason about reuse and even recursion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a sample that might help:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94547af937b22ea8)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    using It     = std::string::const_iterator;

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> m_sName = (qi::alpha | qi::char_('_')) >> *(qi::alnum | qi::char_('_'));

    for (std::string const input : {"foo bar qux_net"}) {
        std::string a, b, c;
        if (phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), m_sName >> m_sName >> m_sName, qi::space, a, b, c)) {
            std::cout << quoted(a) << " " << quoted(b) << " " << quoted(c) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"foo" "bar" "qux_net"
```

#### NOTES

- note I removed `lexeme` because the rule is already skipper-less (see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))
- Note that I'd probably write the rule as [`qi::raw[(qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')]`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86aa0b0b8f95e01e) which can be more efficient. It works well if your attribute reflects the source sequence unmodified.